# How to get random values to a label and a hidden input box using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to web development. Now I am in a mess.
I want to show 4 random questions in a label. Say

1. Largest River in the world?
2. Largest ocean?
3. Largest Forest?
4. Largest Waterfall?

At the same time, the values [questions] should take into a hidden input box [for POST].

How to create it using Java Script?

My HTML Code is as follows

```
<ul class="sf-content"> <!-- form step two --> 
    <li>
        <div class="sf_columns column_3">
            <label id="qtext"> <strong>Question1?</strong></label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="sf_columns column_3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" name="answer" data-required="true" >
            <input id="qhtext" type="text" name="question" value="" readonly /> 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 4 questions in the same label? at the same time as what? what values? what labels? what does a hidden input box have to do with it?

Comment: do you want to take any one random question from provided 4 questions?

Comment: When do you want this to happen?

Comment: @PeeHaa I want the four questions in the same label. That means at a time one question. When I reload my page, the question should change. The four questions should be randomly come in the label. The hidden box is to post the questions to my dtabase because, I know that we can't post the values of a label..

Comment: @ripun Yes i want the questions from the provided 4 questions...

Comment: @Ishetty this should happen on onload of a page...

Comment: Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/calinaadi/ea86mp62/1/ as a starting point and then please edit your question accordingly, because still not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ calinaadi this code is oK.. But I need a slight change..  I require the randomly generated question itself in the second input box. Not the answer...

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/calinaadi/ea86mp62/2/

Comment: @ calinaadi it worked...  Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
<ul class="sf-content"> <!-- form step two --> 
    <li>
        <div class="sf_columns column_3">
            <label id="qtext"></label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="sf_columns column_3">
            <input id="answer" type="text" placeholder="Answer" name="answer" data-required="true" >
            <input id="qhtext" type="text" name="question" value="" readonly /> 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The js is as follows

```
var questions = ["Largest River in the world?","Largest ocean?","Largest Forest?","Largest Waterfall?" ];

$(document).ready(function(){
    getRandomQuestion();   
});
function getRandomQuestion(){   
    //Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); - random number between min and max
    var randomQuestion = questions[ Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
    $("#qtext").text(randomQuestion);
    $("#qhtext").val(randomQuestion);
}
```